# Full line background color

Tags: php, phpword

I´m having a problem with phpword (https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I want to create a line where all the background is one color (100% width), but I can only make the background the size of the text.

```
$titleStyle=array('name' => 'Calibri','size' => 11, 'align' =>'center','marginTop' => 10,'bgColor' => 'd0cece');



    // Create a new table style
    $table_style = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table;
    $table_style->setUnit(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::WIDTH_PERCENT);
    $table_style->setWidth(100 * 50);
    $table_style->setBgColor('d0cece');


    // Set up our table.
    $tableTitle = $section->addTable($table_style);
    $tableTitle->addRow();
    $tableTitle->addCell()->addText('Identificação pessoal',$titleStyle);
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with PhpWord, but have you tried to set width of a cell to 100% of document?

```
$titleStyle = array(
    'name' => 'Calibri',
    'size' => 11,
    'align' =>'center',
    'marginTop' => 10,
    'bgColor' => 'd0cece',
    'width' => 11905.51181102
);
```

From what I see in the docs, cell width needs to be provided in `twip` units, which after conversion from 210mm is `11905.51181102` (A4 page width)

https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en/typography/1-3/twip-centimeter/